# Declare Array Inside Function Call PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function, call

Hey just wondering if there is a simpler way to declare an array inside a function call besides array()

```
$setup = new setupPage();
$setup->setup(array(
                   type => "static",
                   size => 350
                 ));

class setupPage {
    public function setup($config){
        echo $config[size] . $config[type];
    }
}
```

Thanks :D

Comment: **Notice**: Use of undefined constant type - assumed 'type' / **Notice**: Use of undefined constant size - assumed 'size'. Your `size` and `type` should be quoted, i.e., `'size'` and `'type'`. See [Why is `$foo[bar]` wrong?](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar).

Comment: @Pang, good catch, I never looked past the `array()` code =oP

Comment: @cryptic Didn't know PHP 5.4+ has shorthand array literal. Just learned something new from you.

Comment: @Pang http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-82

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use PHP 5.4+ you can use the shorthand, however it makes no difference in performance, but in actuality may make it harder to read:

```
$setup->setup(['type' => 'static',
               'size' => 350]);
```

Comment: Thanks, I must not have 5.4 as I tried that with no luck. I will be sending thru a multi-dimensional array which will start to get messy with all these array() tags

Comment: @str11, as long as your properly indent your code it will be legible with large multinational arrays. Basically do `print_r()` on your array. Try to mimic the indentation it uses for the array to help keep your array code readable where you can easily distinguish what is part of what based on the nesting level.

Comment: You need to quote `type` and `size`, or it issues an `E_NOTICE`.

Comment: See demo [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1feb920deba60f2e45bc7a620dc85f70b79c140f).

Comment: Pang: I will not be using them for anything more than a reference in the array. Thanks for the heads up though.

Answer (score -1):

Create a PHP program with an array (student) with the following
categories: student_id, student_name, student_address,
student_state, student_zip, and student_age. A function within
the program will accept all the values and restrict the data type
passed for each. The function creates the array and place the
values into the array. Display the values in the array. Use try/catch
to display an error message if one or more of the values are not the
proper data type.

Comment: I'm not sure but this sounds more like a separate question.